# Send a message to a specific EventChannel using dart code

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm writing a flutter plugin and I have an `EventChannel` which is used to send messages from Android and iOS to dart. When the code is running in a web platform I need to send some messages to the same `EventChannel` but when the `.listen()` method is called I get the following error:

```
The following MissingPluginException was thrown while activating platform stream on channel
test_channel:
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method listen on channel test_channel)
```

I know it is possible to redirect a specific `MethodChannel` name using the following code:

```
static void registerWith(Registrar registrar) {
// ...
var methodChannel = MethodChannel("myChannelName", const StandardMethodCodec(), registrar);
methodChannel.setMethodCallHandler((call) => plugin.handleMethodCall(methodChannel.name, call));
// ...
}
```

I would like to send events to the `EventChannel("test_channel")` using dart code, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
final MethodChannel methodChannel = MethodChannel("test_channel");

methodChannel.setMethodCallHandler((call) async {
      if (call.method == "Your_method_name") {
// get your data 
// final String message = call.arguments;

}
```

Comment: I need to send messages to the `EventChannel`. Calling the `setMEthodCallHandler` of the `MethodChannle` does not work

Comment: "platform-specific code for the web generally uses JS interoperability or the dart:html library instead."

Did you use https://pub.dev/packages/js?